# PHP. Include with full url across multiple files

Tags: php

Well , i want to know how to do that, let me explain myself.

I have a PHP file where i define some constants, like this one:

```
define('DIR_CORE','http://localhost/Development/Estudio/PHP/mvc/core/');
```

and i include that file(the one with all the variables, I'll call it 'core file'), then i use one of those paths to include a view file, but in that file, which is PHP too, but in that file i have to include again the core file, and then again in another section of the same file that its included.But if i use relative url like :

```
define('DIR_CORE','../../core/');
```

It works in **most of the files** with only one inclusion.
If you're thinking in php.ini | allow_url_include or allow_url_fopen (or so), i have already turn on that.

So:
i want with only one inclusion have all those constants available in main file and included ones too.
There is a way to do this ?.
What security problems could this bring ?

BTW, by this point i'm sure you have already noticed it, but I'm not an English native speaker, and my English isn't good either , but i think that with some effort you could understand this.

Comment: You can look into $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Comment: incldung from an url is not what u want actually im programming. U want to include a file from a local directory. Maybe you searching for `__DIR__`

Comment: @KarloKokkak
Using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], it kinda works, but i get an error when trying to load a js script with this :
 
    "http://localhost/var/www/html/Development/Estudio/PHP/mvc/view/app/js/generals.js". 

which is wrong, and there i just have this 

    'src="<?php echo DIR_JS.'login.js' ?>"'